# How to understand that Inflation generate almost scale-invariant perturbations?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

Since during the inflation, the Hubble rate is approximately constant, the perturbations generated by inflation are almost scale-invariant. How to understand that?

Comment: Inflation is self-similar. It's exponentially increasing the distances in the Universe, $\exp(Ht)$. The perturbations arise at every moment $t$. Their magnitude at length scale $L$ is the same as their magnitude at length scale $eL$ because this scaling by $e$ is equivalent just to a waiting by the time $1/H$.

Comment: And by the way, to find out the degree to which a particular model of inflation violates perfect scale-invariance for the fluctuations, you can calculate the power spectrum of the perturbations and measure the so-called scalar-spectral index (or tilt) $n_s$. A $n_s$ of 1 indicates perfect scale invariance.

Comment: @LubošMotl, Thank you for your answer. If the inflation has a power-law expansion, does it still generates scale-invariant perturbations?

Comment: Nope! A power law expansion is by definition not inflation. The usual big bang is a power law expansion, and it cannot produce a scale-invariant spectrum. Let me be more quantitative. Let's use 10 as the base of the expansion. Inflation has $a = 10^t$, OK? So between t=0 and 1, you get a=1 to 10, between t=1 and 2, you get a=10 to 100, and so on. In every "order of magnitude", the Universe spends the same time, so it has the same opportunity to create the perturbations. That's not true for a power law. The simplest one is a=t. Between t=100 and 101, a only increases by 1%.